# format time & date

Tags: php, formatting

I am fetching two separate variables with time & date as separate values:

`$v['EventDate']` => ***2012-06-13***
`$v['StartTime']` => ***19:00:00***

I would like to present this values in following manner instead:

***June 13th, 2012***
***7:00 PM***

Have tried so far executing it this way:

`echo date("F jS, Y",mktime($v['EventDate']));`
`echo date("F jS, Y",mktime($v['StartTime']));`

And I get proper format but my values keep increasing over time, to June 14th, and time to after 7 :)

Sorry don't have too much time on my hands to go into this so I was hoping for someone experienced with these functions for a quick tip.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 echo date("F jS, Y \n g:i A", strtotime($v['EventDate'].' '.$v['StartTime']));
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `echo date("F jS, Y g:i A",strtotime($v['EventDate'] . " " . $v['StartTime']));`